# I can no longer connect xcode to my iPhone since yesterday

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

The only thing I can think of is upgraded my iPhone iOS.

The iPhone is connected to the mac. I saw my pictures showing up on iMac. There is a connection icon.

However, xcode think that the iPhone is not connected.

What should I do?

I have tried the following:

1. Open another project. Same thing. Xcode doesn't recoqnize the iPhone. There is a listing for my iPhone. However it says `This device is not currently connected.`

Note: Super users people do not use xcode. So they won't know. That's why I asked it here. If it's that problematic can someone move it to superuser now I got answers anyway and got things fixed.

Comment: Does iTunes recognize your iPhone?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your machine/iPhone? That has helped me on occasion in the past.

Comment: Open Organizer-> Devices 1. Check on the left side whether your device is connected i.e. a green icon 2. Is it showing "Use device for Development" 3. Also check your Project targets "Deployment target"

Comment: Is your device jailbroken?

Comment: This should be asked on SuperUser not StackOverflow.

Comment: Super users people do not even use xcode. Also it used to work. This is a bug in xcode and hence relevant mainly for programmers. Maybe you can move this to super user but I think they'll move it back here.

Comment: It says my device is not connected. It uses to connect just fine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ran into the same problem a couple of months ago. you definitely dont need to restore or upgrade the iOS, just need to download and Install "iPhone Configuration Utility" and your iphone will be good for development again.

You can download it from here: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465

Comment: This one works. Thank you.

Comment: with OSX10.9, xCode lost it's ability to see my iPhone with 7.0.x on it,  while it saw the iPad with iOS6.x on it fine...   I had to restart my macPro before it saw the iPhone5 again,   the config utility didn't see it either.   I think in my case it was/Is a OSX 10.9 bug.

Comment: I faced same issue after upgrading to OSX10.9(Maverick) ,to solve this I reinstalled existing "iPhone Configuration Utility"(which will quit the xcode during installation) and suddenly xcode started detecting my devices."Reinstalling  'iPhone Configuration Utility' was the key" Thanks for the clue.

Comment: @AlphonseR.Dsouza cool.. haven't run into this yet. thanks for the heads up.. +1

Answer (score 3):

You need to only upgrade your xcode.

Comment: This answer is actually correct. Why the downvotes? Haters gonna hates.

Comment: Upgrading Xcode was not sufficient for me. I had to run the configuration utility, as described in @Ahmed Z.'s answer

Answer (score 1):

check your xcode..you upgrade you ios to 6.1 then its connect to xcode 4.6.so upgrade your xcode for coonect your device.

Answer (score 0):

I found my iPhone will disconnect while I'm debugging, more specifically editing code, in Xcode even though its physically connected. I think it has to with inactivity on the USB port and/or with the new Xcode version. I find unplugging and re-plugging the phone works. It's annoying I know.

Comment: I upvoted it to mitigate the downvote. However, of course I have tried this.

Answer (score 0):

1. You check the ios version you updated with iphone. If its higher version, say 6.1.4 please update your XCode to a compatible one, say 4.6.
2. Check your deployment taget from project settings
3. Check your base SDK in Build settings to latest IOS

Comment: What is your XCode version and IOS version?